# 18.04 - Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: apt

When I try to install some apps using terminal like `sudo apt-get install vlc` for example, after downloading the whole files it displays this line "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?". I tried them both but they didn't fix the problem.

I tried `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and changed the `nameserver` to `8.8.8.8`, after that it couldn't fetch any link when I try to install anything. Then I changed it to `127.0.0.9` and nothing has changed.

Comment: did you do `sudo apt-get upgrade` after the `update`? Because `upgrade` is here in order to install the update of your packages, `update` for detecting the new version

Comment: you can try also `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I checked that, but I'm facing another problem right now, I ran `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and changed the nameserver. Now it can't fetch any link, can you help me with this ?

Comment: add your error into your question. Why did you edit `resolv.conf`? You have a big message which says  **Don't edit this file by hand**, so if you have change your nameserver, just replace it by `127.0.0.1` and search into `local`

Comment: Nothing has changed, that didn't help!
Can you show me what's inside it in your PC ?